# No puedo acceder al contenido de TabHost

Tags: android

esta vez tengo un problema con un `TabHost` que he creado e inicializado, tiene 3 pestañas, resulta que al contenido de las 2 primeras pestañas no puedo posicionar el foco haciendo click sobre sus `EditText` ni mucho menos hacer click sobre los botones que estos tienen (Parece que el contenido es ineditable, no sé), pero con el contenido de la pestaña 3, si puedo generar eventos, posicionar foco, etc. No sé que suceda o que me aconsejen realizar, agradezco vuestra atención y ayuda.

Codigo XML del TabHost:

```
    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TabHost">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/DatosVehiculo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_width="283dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#63183F"
                        android:id="@+id/lblRelleno" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Típo de Vehículo"
                        android:layout_width="283dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#63183F"
                        android:id="@+id/tipoVehiculo" />
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editTipoVehiculo"
                        android:hint="Típo de Vehículo" />                       

                </LinearLayout>


                <!--Seccion de datos de los operarios-->
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scroll1">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/DatosOperarios"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/lblRelleno1" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Cédula:"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:textColor="#63183F"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/cedulaOperario" />

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:id="@+id/txtCedulaOperario"
                            android:hint="Cédula del Operario" />



                        <!--Contenedor Horizontal de los botones-->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/contenedorBotones"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <Button
                                android:text="Añadir Operario"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                                android:id="@+id/Anadir"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"                                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"                                    android:onClick="AgregarFilaTablaOperarios"/>

                            <Button
                                android:text="Limpiar Formulario"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                                android:id="@+id/Limpiar"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"                                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"                                    android:onClick="LimpiarFormularioOperario"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!--Tabla donde se adicionan los operarios de la cuadrilla-->
                        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/tblOperarios"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:stretchColumns="1" >

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/Cabecera"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ColumnaCedula"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:padding="5px"
                                    android:text="CÉDULA"
                                    android:textColor="#63183F"
                                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ColumnaNombre"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:padding="5px"
                                    android:text="NOMBRE OPERARIO"
                                    android:textColor="#63183F"
                                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ColumnaCargo"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:padding="5px"
                                    android:text="CARGO"
                                    android:textColor="#63183F"
                                    android:textSize="18dp" />
                            </TableRow>

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/SeparadorCabecera"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                                <FrameLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/LineaCabecera"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="2px"
                                    android:layout_span="6"
                                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" >
                                </FrameLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <!--Seccion de registro fotográfico-->
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scroll2">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Fotografias"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <Button
                            android:text="Tomar Foto"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                            android:id="@+id/BtnTomarFoto"
                            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                            android:onClick="TomarFoto"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Código Java de inicialización del control Método OnCreate:

```
TbH = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.TabHost); //llamamos al Tabhost
        TbH.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = TbH.newTabSpec("tab1");  //aspectos de cada Tab (pestaña)
        TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = TbH.newTabSpec("tab2");
        TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = TbH.newTabSpec("tab3");

        tab1.setIndicator("Datos Vehículo");
        tab1.setContent(R.id.DatosVehiculo);

        tab2.setIndicator("Cuadrilla");
        tab2.setContent(R.id.DatosOperarios);

        tab3.setIndicator("Fotografías");
        tab3.setContent(R.id.Fotografias);

        TbH.addTab(tab1); //añadimos los tabs ya programados
        TbH.addTab(tab2);
        TbH.addTab(tab3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo el problema, algunos widgets no pueden tomar el enfoque, esto lo he visto como un "bug" los `ScrollView` al tratar de configurar un movimiento vertical dentro de un `TabHost`, en ocasiones provoca que algunos elementos en los `tabs` se bloqueen, te sugiero quitar los `ScrollView` y un contenedor del `TabHost` con esto todos los elementos obtendrán el enfoque :

Modifiqué tu layout, prueba con este y no tendrás problemas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TabHost">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/DatosVehiculo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_width="283dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#63183F"
                        android:id="@+id/lblRelleno" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Típo de Vehículo"
                        android:layout_width="283dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#63183F"
                        android:id="@+id/tipoVehiculo" />
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editTipoVehiculo"
                        android:hint="Típo de Vehículo" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <!--Seccion de datos de los operarios-->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/DatosOperarios"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/lblRelleno1" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Cédula:"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:textColor="#63183F"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/cedulaOperario" />

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:id="@+id/txtCedulaOperario"
                            android:hint="Cédula del Operario" />



                        <!--Contenedor Horizontal de los botones-->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/contenedorBotones"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <Button
                                android:text="Añadir Operario"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                                android:id="@+id/Anadir"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"                                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"                                    android:onClick="AgregarFilaTablaOperarios"/>

                            <Button
                                android:text="Limpiar Formulario"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                                android:id="@+id/Limpiar"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"                                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"                                    android:onClick="LimpiarFormularioOperario"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!--Tabla donde se adicionan los operarios de la cuadrilla-->
                        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/tblOperarios"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:stretchColumns="1" >

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/Cabecera"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ColumnaCedula"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:padding="5px"
                                    android:text="CÉDULA"
                                    android:textColor="#63183F"
                                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ColumnaNombre"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:padding="5px"
                                    android:text="NOMBRE OPERARIO"
                                    android:textColor="#63183F"
                                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ColumnaCargo"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:padding="5px"
                                    android:text="CARGO"
                                    android:textColor="#63183F"
                                    android:textSize="18dp" />
                            </TableRow>

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/SeparadorCabecera"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                                <FrameLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/LineaCabecera"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="2px"
                                    android:layout_span="6"
                                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" >
                                </FrameLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                <!--Seccion de registro fotográfico-->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Fotografias"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <Button
                            android:text="Tomar Foto"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                            android:id="@+id/BtnTomarFoto"
                            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                            android:onClick="TomarFoto"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfecto amigo, funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias1

Comment: un placer Felipe, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ